# How to create rocket with burning fuel animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

I need to create a rocket going up from bottom of the screen to the top and fuel ejecting out of its lower end. I have created the rocket animation but I am not sure how to achieve the latter. Thanks

```
public void rocketLaunch() {

    final ObjectAnimator rotate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rocket, "translationY", 100f, -1400f); //150f,-80f
    rotate.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
    rotate.setRepeatCount(1); 
    rotate.setDuration(8000); 

    rotate.start();

}
```

Comment: Just alternate some PNGs, each showing different states of the flame, to give the impression of a dynamic exhaust.

Comment: For the images, I'd use some brightness and color variations. And some subtle shape change too (i.e.: like a "fire-snake").

Comment: Something like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6276iWx6qwA

Answer (score 0):

You need to get about 6 images for this animation. Each one with the rocket flames coming out a little further.

Put the images into a list

Take the node you are going to apply this image to.

In a runnable timer handler & using a while or for loop, tell the node to display the next image in the list every .25 seconds(or faster)

Comment: I'd say **some** images, not necessarily 6. And not necessarily going back and forth. I'd use some brightness and color variations. And some subtle shape change too (i.e.: like a "fire-snake").

Comment: yeah he's right. also consider using andEngine with box2d physics. It includes methods for animation that make this process simpler.

Comment: my guy, youve got to accept one of these world class answers that surely answered your question

Answer (score 0):

Animation consists of many still images, also known as frames, that are displayed one by one over a specified time period.

Elapsed time between frames is named frame refresh delay — it’s 10 ms by default for property animations.

In the beginning of the animation, the rocket is at the bottom edge of the screen.
The rocket’s position moves upward by the same fraction of its path with every frame.
By the end of the animation, the rocket is at the top edge of the screen.

[image]

Follow this tutorial
 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/128105/introduction-android-animations

Comment: I have followed the example listed in the link above. And now using the code. Thanks. Can you please help me out with on how to achieve the fuel animation also

Comment: go through all examples from that link ,one with dog image moving up with rocket ,may be useful for you.